# spark-submit in cluster mode. not able to transfer application jar to driver node

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have 3 node cluster node A,B,C. running master on A ,B and slave on A.B and C. 
while i run spark-submit from node A using below command.

```
/usr/local/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit   --class com.test.SparkExample --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --master spark://master.com:7077  file:///home/spark/sparkstreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

the driver gets launched to node B and it tries to find application jar at local file system at node B. do we need to transfer application jar on each master node manually.  is the the known bug ? or i am missing something.
kindly suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the official documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html it should be present on every node.

By the way, it is possible to put file in `hdfs`.